# Java - looking for a good way to store and synchronize e-mails with server using IMAP

Tags: java, email, client, jakarta-mail

I want to create local mail client in Java (like Thunderbird or Outlook). I download all the mails using JavaMail and IMAP but i want to store mail messages/folders on local disk and synchronize them with server and i am looking for a good way to do so, i consider:

1. mbox - i guess that it would be the best but cant find any implementation in Java that would download from server/create mbox/update mbox/read mbox.
2. SQLite to store mails - it is hard to estimate performance with large scale mails

I will appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give a try to orientdb? its lightweight, faster and distributed with apache license.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825491/are-there-any-embeddable-document-database-engines-for-java-something-similar-t
official site - 
http://orientdb.com/orientdb/

Comment: i dont think that any database, especially object oriented, will be much faster than SQLite (with hibernate, workflow is the same like with object oriented), the question is about strategy when you have one file with all the mail messages vs "file"/db row per message and maybe some libraries with implementation

Comment: yeah, true. SQLite is probably best option. apache James has implementation for for mbox, but it will come with some overhead, I think. I heard of something names mStor out here. You may want to take a look as well. http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=545023